# Pandas conditions on count()

Tags: pandas, plot

Hi hoping this is not a silly question.

I have a dataframe from which I am plotting a chart based on how many times something appears with the following code.

```
df.groupby('name').name.count().plot.bar()
plt.xlabel('Name')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.title('Number of times name appears')
```

Is there a way to get it to only plot those names that appear a certain amount of times? I am guessing I need some kind of function but not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `value_counts`

```
df.name.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Edit :

```
df.group1.value_counts().compress(lambda s: s>=8).plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: All that seems to do is show them in sorted order. I only want to show those names that appear 8 or more times.